# What's the best way of adding a floating "completer" to qtextedit in pyqt?

Tags: python, pyqt, widget, qtextedit, qcompleter

I want to add a completer for symbol names for qtextedit, its behavior looks like a completer, but how can I make it 'floating' on top of my qtextedit?

The result I'm looking for is similar to what sublime editor does.  when you press ctrl+r, you get

[image]